# Retrieve the FormLevel Notification in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online

Is there any way of getting the Field Level Notification as we set the Notification in Dynamics CRM Client Scripting.

[image]

Like `formcontext.getControl("fieldname").getNotification` . I could not find any method like getNotification ?

Please assist me with how can I get the field level display error message (which is thrown by the Microsoft Out of the box Script) ?

Note - I have tried the object of the field and check all the properties and methods to return error message or error code. Could not locate any.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `formContext.getControl(arg).setNotification(message,uniqueId)` to set your field notifications, the only reference to that notification is the `uniqueId` that you passed in.

You can use `formContext.getControl(arg).clearNotification(uniqueId)` to clear the notification afterwards, but you can't edit the existing Notification once it is in place.

If you want to change the wording, you could try clearing, and then setting a new notification.